# How to create a nested object by joining tables with Spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to join multiple tables with Spring JPA in order to receive a nested object, but something seems to be wrong with my query that I've set in my repository interface.

**This is the desired output (it is only a simplified example)**

```
[departmentId: 1
 departmentName: A
 employees:[
    [employeeId: 100
    employeeName: John],
    [employeeId: 200
    employeeName: Carl]],
[departmentId: 2
 departmentName: B
 employees:[
    [employeeId: 300
    employeeName: Nancy]]
```

**I have the following tables in Postgres:**

department: department_id, department_name

employees: employee_id, employee_name, department_id

**These are my classes:**

**Department**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="department_id")
private Integer departmentId;

@Column(name="department_name")
private String departmentName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
private List<Employee> employees;
}
//getters, setters, etc.
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="employee_id")
private Integer employeeId;

@Column(name="employee_name")
private String employeeName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;
}
//getters, setters, etc.
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT department.department_id, department_name, employee_id,  employee_name FROM department " +
        "JOIN employees ON employees.department_id = department.department_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<Department> findDeps();
```

}

But I'm getting a LazyInitializationException. I've read that setting FetchType.EAGER is not recommended, but even that is throwing a StackOverFlow error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By removing the ManyToOne annotation and changing the Query to "SELECT d FROM Department d JOIN FETCH d.employees" it seems to work, however since my real case is much more complex, I planned to define a native query instead. Is there any way to make it work like that?

Answer (score 0):

This Projection worked for me for the native query

```
    SELECT department.department_name as deptName,
     department.department_desc as deptDesc, 
    employee.employee_id empId,  
    employee.employee_name empName 
    FROM department
    JOIN employees 
    ON employees.department_id = department.department_id
```

---

```
    package mypackage;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    
    public interface EmpDeptDTO {
        String getEmpId();
        String getEmpDesc();
        @Value("#{@departmentMapper.buildDepartmentDTO(target.deptName, target.deptDesc)}")
        DepartmentDTO getDepartment();
    }
```

---

```
    import lombok.Data;
    
    @Data
    public class DepartmentDTO {
        private String deptName;
        private String deptDesc;
    }
```

---

```
@Component
public class DeparmentMapper {
public DepartmentDTO buildDepartmentDTO(String deptName, String deptDesc) {
        DepartmentDTO  deptDTO= new DepartmentDTO ();
        deptDTO.setDeptName(deptName);
        deptDTO.setDeptDesc(deptDesc);
        return deptDTO;
    }
}
```